# Spark "CodeGenerator: failed to compile" with Dataset.groupByKey

Tags: scala, exception, apache-spark, code-generation

I'm new to both Scala and Spark, so hopefully someone can let me know where I'm going wrong here.

I have a three-column dataset (id, name, year) and I want to find the most recent year for each name.  In other words:

```
BEFORE                                          AFTER
| id_1 | name_1 | 2015 |                        | id_2 | name_1 | 2016 |
| id_2 | name_1 | 2016 |                        | id_4 | name_2 | 2015 |
| id_3 | name_1 | 2014 | 
| id_4 | name_2 | 2015 |
| id_5 | name_2 | 2014 |
```

I thought `groupByKey` and `reduceGroups` would get the job done:

```
val latestYears = ds
  .groupByKey(_.name)
  .reduceGroups((left, right) => if (left.year > right.year) left else right)
  .map(group => group._2)
```

But it gives this error, and spits out a lot of generated Java code:

```
ERROR CodeGenerator: failed to compile: 
org.codehaus.commons.compiler.CompileException: 
File 'generated.java', Line 21, Column 101: Unknown variable or type "value4"
```

Interestingly, if I create a dataset with just the name and year columns, it works as expected.

---

Here's the full code I'm running:

```
object App {

  case class Record(id: String, name: String, year: Int)

  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val spark = SparkSession.builder().master("local").appName("test").getOrCreate()
    import spark.implicits._

    val ds = spark.createDataset[String](Seq(
        "id_1,name_1,2015",
        "id_2,name_1,2016",
        "id_3,name_1,2014",
        "id_4,name_2,2015",
        "id_5,name_2,2014"
      ))
      .map(line => {
        val fields = line.split(",")
        new Record(fields(0), fields(1), fields(2).toInt)
      })

    val latestYears = ds
      .groupByKey(_.name)
      .reduceGroups((left, right) => if (left.year > right.year) left else right)
      .map(group => group._2)

    latestYears.show()
  }


}
```

---

**EDIT:** I believe this may be a bug with Spark v2.0.1.  After downgrading to v2.0.0, this no longer occurs.

Comment: Same problem here, I worked around the issue by converting the reduceGroups().map(_._2) to a mapGroups(_.reduce(_._2)). Did you already report this issue to the spark mailing list/issue tracker?

Comment: That might be a bug, but am more _concerned_ with the code itself. Why don't you use `groupBy` and `max` on `year`? It uses untyped DataFrame API (not Dataset) though. Any particular reason?

Answer (score 0):

Your `groupBy` and `reduceGroups` functions are [experimental](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.1/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset@groupByKey[K](func:org.apache.spark.api.java.function.MapFunction[T,K],encoder:org.apache.spark.sql.Encoder[K]):org.apache.spark.sql.KeyValueGroupedDataset[K,T]). Why not use `reduceByKey` ([api](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions@reduceByKey(func:(V,V)=%3EV):org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(K,V)]))?

Pros:

- It should be easy to translate from the code you have.
- It is more stable (not experimental).
- It should be more efficient because it does not require a complete shuffle of all the items in each groups (which can also create network I/O slow downs and overflow the memory in a node).